# getpass module for wlst

Tags: python, importerror, wlst

I am trying to get input for password in wlst script. I saw on one of the post that getpass module will be usefull but when I am trying with it I am getting below error

```
ImportError: no module named getpass
```

So how to make this correct?

Comment: How are you importing that module? Show us the import statement. AFAIK `import getpass` should succeed in any reasonable version of python. (I just checked and Jython provides it too, so either you are using a really unusual interpreter or you are using the wrong import statement.)

Comment: I am having a big script so cannot paste that script. To confirm this logic I am using a small script as mentioned 
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
import getpass
from java.util import *
from javax.management import *
import javax.management.Attribute
from java.io import *



password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password:")
print password
exit()

Comment: I am using it in weblogic server and running it with the help of wlst. My weblogic server version is 10.3. Please guide me. Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Instead of putting it into a comment can you edit the question and copy paste that code? However, as far as I can tell, your import is correct.

Comment: getpass() module is not present in the Jython version that WLST uses. You can use Java's java.io.Console console = java.lang.System.console(); console.readPassword() APIs. [Check this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Linux machine there could be Python installed alread, it is having this getpass module in the libraries directory. You need to copy the getpass.py file from there to  ${WL_HOME}/common/wlst/modules path and start WLST shell try to import getpass. It worked on my cute UBUNTU :)

```
pavanwla@wlatraings:/usr/lib/python2.7$ cp getpass.py ~/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/common/wlst/modules
```

Invoke WLST SHELL (worked on WebLogic 12c but same thing works on 11g also) and see

```
1. wls:/offline> import getpass
wls:/offline>
```